# DRF: Let serializer filter related objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the three models listed below. When I serialize media objects, owners are listed just like they should. The trough-table holds an `is_accepted` value, and what I would like is for the media serializer to only list owners that have acepter their media. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**Models:**

```
class Media(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Usermedia', related_name='owners')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Usermedia(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='usermedia')
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ownership')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=1)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
```

**Serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[validators.UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    genre = serializers.SlugRelatedField(required=True, slug_field='name', queryset=Genre.objects.all())
```

Thank you for taking your time to look at this

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a `SerializerMethodField`.

My serializer now looks like this:

```
class MediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owners = SerializerMethodField()
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    genre = serializers.SlugRelatedField(required=True, slug_field='name', queryset=Genre.objects.all())

    def get_owners(self, obj):
        ownerships = obj.ownership.all()
        owners = [ownership.user for ownership in ownerships if (ownership.is_active and ownership.is_accepted)]

        return UserSerializer(owners, many=True).data
```

One tip is to make sure to prefetch the related fields before passing the results to the serializer, or else the serializer will be doing lookups to the database for every instance it parses.